# How to use Gitlab IDE's client side evaluation to live preview my Harp site?

Tags: gitlab, harp

I'm trying to make a Gitlab pages static site with Harp by following [their example](https://gitlab.com/pages/harp) and I want to use [Gitlab IDE's client side evaluation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/web_ide/#enabling-client-side-evaluation) feature to be able to preview it as I write.

It says I have to create a `package.json` file with a main script, but I'm not writing a package, it's just a website!

So how could I achieve that? Thanks!